# Собственный макрос в css

Tags: css, макросы

Я написал 2 стиля. И их я буду применять часто к единичным словам. Скажите, пожалуйста, есть ли в CSS возможность присвоения имени (возможно, с параметрами) последовательности уже определенных в CSS команд с целью вызова этой последовательности команд написанием этого имени (возможно, с параметрами) ?

Comment: Не понятно ничего, от слова совсем

Comment: Смотрите. Приведу аналог из LaTeX. Там есть команда \newcommand. Ей пользуются так: допустим, я написал так: ``` \newcommand{\smb}[2]{\left(\frac{#1}{#2}\right}}``` Это значит, я определил новую команду \smb, зависящую от двух параметров (в коде это указано частью *[2]*), смысл которой в том, что она в выходном пдф создает дробь (в коде *\frac*), в числителе которой стоит параметр #1, а в знаменателе - параметр #2, окруженную слева (в коде *\left(* ) и справа (в коде *\right(* ) круглыми скобками. Таким образом, последующая команда \smb{a+b){c} порождает

Comment: <script src='https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML'></script>
<h2>$$\left(\frac{a+b}{c}\right)$$</h2>

Comment: <!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->

<!-- language: lang-html -->

    <script src='https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML'></script>
    <h2>$$\left(\frac{a+b}{c}\right)$$</h2>

<!-- end snippet -->

Answer (score 2):

В комменте не работает, вставлю в ответ, хотя и не по правилам, за что извиняюсь.

```html
<script src='https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML'></script>
<h2>$$\Bigl(\frac{a+b}{c}\Bigr)$$</h2>
```

Answer (score 2):

Макросов в CSS нет. Если хочется облегчить себе работу - пользуйтесь LESS или другим препроцессором. А превращать симпатичный плоский код в инженерного монстра не надо.

А в вашем случае вместо команды к единичным словам нужно применять css-классы или атрибуты.